# Apache .htaccess rewrite rule to redirect urls from sub-directory to parent directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am looking for an Apache .htaccess rewrite rule to redirect urls from sub-directory to parent directory.

Following is the use case:

URL Redirects:

```
http://localhost/content/videos redirects (302) to http://localhost/videos
http://localhost/content/article/some-awesome-article redirects (302) to http://localhost/article/some-awesome-article
http://localhost/content/some-html-file.html redirects (302) to http://localhost/some-html-file.html
etc.
```

While the following should not:

```
http://localhost/content/some-image.jpg
http://localhost/content/admin (Specific)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^content/((?!admin|some-image\.jpg).+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

---

**EDIT:** Using `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/content/((?!(admin|(.*\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png|css|js|woff|ttf|svg|eot|GIF|JPEG|JPG‌​|PNG|CSS|JS|WOFF|TTF|SVG|EOT)))).+)$ /$1
```

Comment: Are there rules before this rule? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: I used this:

RedirectMatch 302  ^/content/((?!(admin|(.*\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png|css|js|woff|ttf|svg|eot|GIF|JPEG|JPG|PNG|CSS|JS|WOFF|TTF|SVG|EOT)))).+)$ /$1

It worked.

Comment: ok good that is similar negative regex rule pattern as I suggested in answer.